# testing if a numpy array is symmetric?

Tags: python, matrix, numpy

Is there a better pythonic way of checking if a ndarray is diagonally symmetric in a particular dimension? i.e for all of x

```
(arr[:,:,x].T==arr[:,:,x]).all()
```

I'm sure I'm missing an (duh) answer but its 2:15 here... :)

EDIT: to clarify, I'm looking for a more 'elegant' way to do :

```
for x in range(xmax):
    assert (arr[:,:,x].T==arr[:,:,x]).all()
```

Comment: I think that your method is perfectly reasonable, and I can't think of a built-in function that tests symmetry that would do this in a more concise/efficient way.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to do the check

```
all((arr[:,:,x].T==arr[:,:,x]).all() for x in range(arr.shape[2]))
```

without the Python loop.  Here is how to do it:

```
(arr.transpose(1, 0, 2) == arr).all()
```

Answer (score 13):

If your array contains floats (especially if they're the result of a computation), use [`allclose`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html)

```
np.allclose(arr.transpose(1, 0, 2), arr)
```

If some of your values might be `NaN`, set those to a marker value before the test.

```
arr[np.isnan(arr)] = 0
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `np.transpose` shouldn't change the values, only their positions, so they should be really equal.

Comment: @moi `allclose` is only necessary if you're testing on floats and those floats are the result of a computation or other potentially precision reducing operation. However, it's a good habit to have in general, for avoiding surprises.

Answer (score 1):

I know you asked about NumPy. But SciPy, NumPy sister package, has a build-in function called `issymmetric` to check if a 2D NumPy array is symmetric. You can use it too.

```
>>> from scipy.linalg import issymmetric
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(27).reshape(3,3,3)
>>> a
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8]],

       [[ 9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17]],

       [[18, 19, 20],
        [21, 22, 23],
        [24, 25, 26]]])
>>> for i in range(a.shape[2]):
    issymmetric(a[:,:,i])

False
False
False
>>>
```