# Index error when looping through matrix elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix

I need to test if a matrix is symmetric or not. If it is symmetric, the function needs to return 0, and if not, then it returns 1. To me, this code makes sense, but I don't understand the error that's popping up.

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-903eff7c516e> in <module>()
     20 # here's the matrix I'm testing :
     21 
---> 22 isSymmetric(np.matrix(([(1,0,0),(5,6,5),(8,0,1)])))

<ipython-input-3-903eff7c516e> in isSymmetric(A)
     10     i=0
     11     for i in np.matrix(A) :
---> 12         m = A[i]
     13         n = A[:,i]
     14         if m==n :

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/matrixlib/defmatrix.pyc in __getitem__(self, index)
    316 
    317         try:
--> 318             out = N.ndarray.__getitem__(self, index)
    319         finally:
    320             self._getitem = False

IndexError: index 5 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3
```

Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np

def isSymmetric (A) :
    """ 
     A : the matrix that will be checked if it's symmetric

     """

    #check if rows are same as columns 
    i=0
    for i in np.matrix(A) :
        m = A[i]
        n = A[:,i]
        if m==n :
            print(1)
        else:
            print(0)


# here's the matrix I'm testing :

isSymmetric(np.matrix(([(1,0,0),(5,6,5),(8,0,1)])))
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320324/testing-if-a-numpy-array-is-symmetric

Comment: Your code is incorrectly indented, fix that.

Comment: Please copy and paste your error message into your question instead of using an image. It is more readable.

Comment: I've made the edits for you. One of the things that I changed was your title. The reason is that the problem you are having is not specific to symmetric matrices or testing symmetric matrices. It is a problem with how you index matrices. That's also what the error message tells you. The new title will help other people with the same problem find your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest there are a bunch of things wrong with your code. The reason you're getting the warning (and my version has an outright error) is this:

```
i=0
for i in np.matrix(A) :
```

This doesn't make any sense. `for i in container` will loop by setting `i` equal to all of the things inside the container in succession. In this case the container is `np.matrix(A)`, so it's looping through every actual item in the array. Obviously these don't make sense when you then use them as an index. If you want to loop over the indexes, you need something like:

```
M = np.matrix(A)
for i in range(M.shape[0]):
```

This loops over all the possible values for the first index of the matrix.

By the way, a much neater way to do this is by using the concise definition of a symmetric matrix, i.e. transpose(M) = M. You can do this in Python as:

```
def is_symmetric(M):
    return (M == M.transpose()).all()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'm a beginner programmer so I don't really know eactly what I'm doing. Also, I tried the more concise code and I'm getting the error " AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'transpose' " any suggestions ?

Comment: @Katey Yeah, `transpose` is a method of matrices, so you need to pass a matrix to that function. In your code you were converting `A` to a matrix every time you ran the loop, which is very inefficient. It's better if you convert `A` to a matrix, storing it in a variable (e.g. `M`) if necessary, and then doing the loop on it.

Comment: @Katey By the way, please accept this answer if it helped you figure out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Testing if a matrix is symmetric would be done with something like `np.all(A == A.T)`. `A.T` gives the transposed matrix and `==` checks equlity **elementwise**, so checking if for all elements you get `True` with `np.all` after the `==` lets you eventually know if your matrix is symmetric.

However, if you are working with floating points it is useful to introduce some finite tolerance. `==` has tolerance zero which is not always good when working with floating points. Instead you can use `np.allclose(A, A.T)` here.

These methods return either `True` or `False`. If you want to stick with `1` and `0`, you can return `1 * <return value of np.all or np.allclose>`.